# Is there a way to make extension-method with List<T>, method(T) as parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, system.reactive, generic-list

I need to make extension method which takes `List<>` of any type (`List<T>`) as the first parameter with `this`(because it is an extension) and a method which takes parameter with same type as the list (`Method(T some_parameter)`) as the second parameter. Inside of this method I need to make some manipulations of every item in `List<T>`.

I am not very good in understanding if `delegate` and `Delegate`, just can't get it. I tried to use `delegates`, `Delegates`, Lambda expressions, but nothing...

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
       List<item> lisd = new List<item>();
       list.CallForEach((List <item> _list) => EXTENDER.Method(_list));
  }

  public static class EXTENDER
  {

       public static void Method<T>(List<T> list)
       {
            //some code 
       }

       public static void CallForEach<T>(this List<T> list, Action<T> action)
       {
            foreach(var item in list)
            {
                 action(item);
            }
       }
  }
```

Am i need to use exactly 'Action'? 
Send me refs if somebody knows something about similar methods...

Comment: Read about `Linq` there are lots of stuff with the similar interface

Comment: The way you're doing it is fine; that's why `Action<T>` was invented.

Comment: If you want to do something on every element of the list, don't pass a function that operates on `List<item>`, but a function that operates on `item`.

Comment: If you want to operate on each `T` instead of the source `List<T>` then `List<T>` already has the [`ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) method that does this.

Comment: `lisd.CallForEach(oneItem => Console.WriteLine(oneItem.SomePropertyOfItem));`. As Lee notes, there's already a method in `List<T>` for that, but it's a good exercise to write your own.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code as shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For academic purposes

**Given**

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static void MethodEx<T>(this T item)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
   }

   public static void CallForEach<T>(this List<T> list, Action<T> action)
   {
      foreach (var item in list)
         action(item);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void Method<T>(T item)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var list = new List<int>()
                 {
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5,
                    6
                 };

   list.CallForEach(x => x.MethodEx());

   // or you could use a method group
   list.CallForEach(Extension.MethodEx);

   //or if its not in your extension class
   list.CallForEach(Method);


   // ForEach is already part of the List class
   list.ForEach(x => x.MethodEx());
   list.ForEach(Extension.MethodEx);
   list.ForEach(Method);

}
```

**Output** of all examples

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Note: You can call `list.CallForEach(Extension.MethodEx)` as well.

Comment: `list.CallForEach(x => x.MethodEx())` `x.` have only 6 default int methods and can't see any of: `MethodEx<T>(T item)` or `MethodEx<int>(int item)` or `MethodEx<T>(this T item)` or `MethodEx<T>(this List<T> item)`. What can i do wrong? Also any of my tries with `ForEach` crushed...